# How to transform form tag code into a page that have a master page?

Tags: asp.net, forms, master-pages, action, html

I have asp.net web page that have the following :

```
<form id="WebCaptureForm" name="WebCaptureForm" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post 
    action="http://site/page.aspx?idn=1&tr=100d1165&action=savenew">
```

I want to make new page with master page that contain the same code but how can i make the above code in a web page that have a master page

Answer (score 1):

Since this `<form>` isn't a server-side form (`runat="server"`), you shouldn't have any trouble using it in a master page. Note that:

- A `<form>` cannot be nested in another `<form>`.
- Any page in asp.net can only have a single (visible) server-side `<form>`.
- If you do want a server-side `<form>`, you can't really control its `name`, `id`, `method` and `action`. Action is the hardest one here, as in general, you want each page to post-back to itself.

If you want to have that code is a single page, you can create another `ContentPlaceHolder`, and place is in the maste page, outside of your main `<form>` tag.